# Can a Delegate have an optional parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, optional-parameters

I have the below code that was working fine until I tried adding the `bool NetworkAvailable = true` portion.  Now I get a `Method name expected` compile time exception at Line 4 below.

```
void NetworkStatus_AvailabilityChanged(object sender, NetworkStatusChangedArgs e)
{
   var networkAvailable = e.IsAvailable;
   SetUpdateHUDConnectedMode d = new SetUpdateHUDConnectedMode(UpdateHUDConnectedMode(networkAvailable));
   this.Invoke(d);
}   

delegate void SetUpdateHUDConnectedMode(bool NetworkAvailable = true);
private void UpdateHUDConnectedMode(bool NetworkAvailable = true)
{
   ...
}
```

I am, admittedly, new to `Delegates` and `Optional Parameters` so I would be grateful for any insight.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A delegate points to a method definition.
When you instantiate a delegate pointing to a method, you cannot specify any parameters.

Instead, you need to pass the parameter values to the `Invoke` method, like this:

```
SetUpdateHUDConnectedMode d = UpdateHUDConnectedMode;
this.Invoke(d, e.IsAvailable);
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like my delegate needs to have the parameter declared as well, like this -->`        delegate void SetUpdateHUDConnectedMode(bool NetworkAvailable = true);
`, correct?  I am assuming so since it won't compile the other way but...

Comment: Yes; the delegate _definition_ must define which parameters the delegate takes.  A delegate type defines a function signature which the method(s) in the delegate must match.

Comment: That is what I thought too.  I am glad I am on the right track as `delegates` are turning out to be not, quite, as bad as I thought they would.

Comment: Note, by the way, that you can also use the built-in generic `Action<bool>` delegate.

Comment: I will have to read up on generic delegates as I have not used them.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Kind of a follow up question but do I have to include a parameter with my Invoke call now?  This like of code, elsewhere, now throws a runtime exception. `this.Invoke(d);`

Comment: The WinForms `Invoke` method is not aware of optional parameters.  Therefore, you need to pass every parameter to `Invoke`.   The delegate itself is aware of optional parameters, so you can (but don't want to) write `d();` without parameters.

Comment: So for WinForms does that, somewhat, defeat the point of Optional Parameters?

Answer (score 29):

To some very limited extent. Using C# 4 :

```
 public delegate void Test(int a, int b = 0);

 static void T1(int a, int b) { }
 static void T2(int a, int b = 0) { }
 static void T3(int a) { }


    Test t1 = T1;
    Test t2 = T2;
    Test t3 = T3;   // Error
```

And  then you can call

```
    t1(1);
    t1(1, 2);
    t2(2);
    t2(2, 3);
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a C# 5 feature, but in your example you could declare `static void T2(int a, int b = 1) { }` for example and it'll still not error until `t3`. It looks like delegate/signature matches simply work on the basis of matching optional parameters, rather than the default value.