# Calling a method with optional parameter by delegate’s instance

Tags: c#, delegates, instance-variables, optional-parameters

We know that we can reference to methods by using delegates and can call the methods by calling the instance of delegate.

I want to call a method(which has an optional parameter) by calling instance of  delegate.

My code is below

```
using System;

namespace Testing_Delegates
{
    class Program
    {
        delegate void Order(string abc);
        public static void ReverseOrder(string rev = "Optional Param")
        {
            char[] elements = rev.ToCharArray();
            char[] reversed = new char[rev.Length];
            for(int i = 0; i < rev.Length; i++)
            {
                reversed[i] = elements[rev.Length - (i+1)];
            }
            foreach(char element in reversed)
            {
                Console.Write(element);
            }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Order changeorder = new Order(ReverseOrder);
            changeorder();//------Here is error------------
        }
    }
}
```

Error is

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'abc' of 'Program.Order'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a Delegate have an optional parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763037/can-a-delegate-have-an-optional-parameter)

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. The delegate *signature* only knows about its own parameters (just like an Interface) and not about the delegate *implementation*. If you don't want to duplicate code, you can make the delegate signature accept the optional string and remove the optional string from the actual method implementation.

Answer (score 2):

To get this to work you need to add the optional parameter to your delegate declaration as well.  The declaration of the delegate should be:

```
delegate void Order(string abc = "Optional Param");
```

The default string can be any compile-constant string value.

Should also mention that doing this means that the ReverseOrder method doesn't need to have the optional parameter.  It can be declared as:

```
public static void ReverseOrder(string rev) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

The delegate's signature requires a parameter to be set. You will need to provide the value for string abc and also invoke like so:

```
changeorder.Invoke("hello world");
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the default value to the delegate as well, like

```
delegate void Order(string abc = "Optional Parameter");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need your delegate signatures to also support optional parameter, currently your method signature and delegate signature are not same:

```
delegate void Order(string abc="");
```