# How to invoke a delegate with optional params?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I have the following:

```
var availableDelegates = new Dictionary<string, SampleHandler>{
    {"TestWithNoParams", SampleHandlerOne }, // this is what I have now - working
    {"TestWithParamSetA", SampleHandlerTwo } // need this
    {"TestWithNoParams", SampleHandlerTwo } // and this - working
}

public static SampleHandler SampleHandlerOne(){
     // do stuff - working
}

// v1
public static SampleHandler SampleHandlerTwo(){
     // do stuff without parameters - working
}

// v2
public static SampleHandler SampleHandlerTwo(HandlerTwoParams params = null) { // trying to update to support optional params
     // do stuff with parameters - not working
     // params.Foo = bar
}
```

How can I pass optional parameters to a delegate?  The idea would be that I can do:

```
if (someCondition)
    availableDelegates[target].Invoke(optionalParams);
else
    availableDelegates[target].Invoke();
```

Comment: SampleHandler does not appear to have optional parameters.  So this can't work.

Comment: @HansPassant - that's why there's `v1` and `v2` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve exactly what you're looking for with optional parameters on your delegate methods, passing the parameters via the `Invoke` method. This previous answer shows how this can be done: [Can a Delegate have an optional parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763037/can-a-delegate-have-an-optional-parameter)